# How can I make gradle ignore host key checking when uploadArchives is called?

Tags: android, ssh, gradle, aar

I have a library that is being build within a Travis CI instance. After the build completes, I would like it to upload the artifact using `./gradlew uploadArchives`. The problem right now is that, while I can do this locally, the Travis instance doesn't have my server key in its `.ssh/known_hosts` file (it probably doesn't even HAVE a `.ssh/known_hosts` file.

I am using the following configuration of `uploadArchives` in my gradle configuration:

```
uploadArchives {                                                                
  repositories {                                                                
    mavenDeployer {                                                             
      pom.packaging = "aar"                                                     
      pom.groupId = project.CORE_GROUP                                          
      pom.version = project.CORE_VERSION_NAME                                   
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             
}                                                                               

gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask { Task aTask ->                                     
  if (aTask == uploadArchives) {                                                
    checkArtifactPublishProperties()                                            
    aTask.repositories.mavenDeployer.configuration = configurations.deployerJars
    aTask.repositories.mavenDeployer.repository(url: "scp://" + project.publishArtifactHost + ":" + getArtifactTargetDirectory()) {
      authentication(userName: project.publishArtifactUsername, privateKey: ext.publishArtifactKeyFile)
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             
}
```

I'm not sure how to specify the `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` as a parameter to this method. My gut tells me that I have to add it to the configuration `configurations.deployerJars`, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Can someone point me to the documentation for this and perhaps provide a sample of how I might go about this?

Comment: Can please change the headline cause this question is only Gradle related and not maven related.